# What are those zigzagged folded paper things you see in supernatural anime?

Tags: culture

In a lot of supernatural anime, like *Shin Sekai Yori*, or *Tokyo Ravens* there often appear these large ropes with folded paper things hanging from them:

[image: sacred barrier]

As far as I can tell, they serve to seal or mark places that are sacred or in some way supernatural, like *shinboku*, or holy trees:

[image: shinboku]

What are these folded paper things, and what purpose do they really serve?

Comment: It's a [shide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shide_(Shinto)). You question is also off-topic, unless you care to rephrase it in the scope of an anime or manga.

Comment: Sadly we're not [Japanese Culture.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59039/japanese-culture)

Comment: Oh.. I looked and couldn't find anything like that >.<

Comment: This question primarily pertains to [Japanese Culture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59039/japanese-culture) rather than Anime or Manga. If you would revise your question to be more about the use of this in anime and manga subculture or a particular series you saw it in, it might be more on-topic for this site.

Comment: Well, you basically gave me the answer, so the question should just be closed or deleted

Comment: I personally think that if you could rephrase it it would be useful to a lot of other people. Having it as it right now might give other ppl the idea that it's okay to ask stuff about Japanese culture that they just happen to see in a manga. It's like asking on Stack Overflow about "code" you saw in a movie.

Comment: edited to put it more on topic, or something

Comment: The first image does not show up with anything other than some warning about "bandwidth theft" to me.

Comment: Oh, great. I'll find another one soon

Comment: Alright there, first image fixed

Comment: Though this question has been edited, the current version still isn’t asking about a facet of _shide_ that, rather than being cultural, specifically pertains to _Shin Sekai Yori_ or to _Tokyo Ravens_, or to some plot element that both series feature, so I don't think it fits as on-topic yet. Perhaps expanding on the "What purpose do they really serve?" part of your question would help (something along the lines of "Do they succeed in protecting something in this story, or are evil/impure forces still managing to wreak havoc even though they're hanging there?" or "Are _shide_ generally . . ."

Comment: “. . . portrayed as effective or non-effective [benign] as purification or protection in anime series? Do characters rely on them or feel a need to supplement them with other items/abilities/training? Are antagonists concerned about their goals being thwarted by the presence of _shide_?”).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The zigzagged paper streamer things you mention are called "[shide](http://eos.kokugakuin.ac.jp/modules/xwords/entry.php?entryID=316)." They are in essence wards for purification. They are often seen with the rice straw rope they are attached to are called "[shimenawa](http://www.swarthmore.edu/Humanities/pschmid1/array/convolute3/shimenawa.html)." Together they marks the boundary to something sacred (or rather mark the boundary between the sacred and that which is not) and can typically be found can be found on torii gates, around sacred trees and stones, etc. They are intended to keep impurities out and purify the space within.

As the same time, they can also be use to prevent, or rather seal the passage of gods. According to the Kojiki (a oral collection of myths forming the basis of the Shinto religion.), shimenawa was first used to prevent the sun goddess Amaterasu from re-entering a cave to save the world from eternal night.

In the *Shin Sekai Yori* anime, it's mentioned "evil spirits" and "monsters" are roam outside the town and any child who ventures out alone would suffer terribly. Hacchijoume is the shimenawa that encircles Kamisu's District 66, erecting a sacred barrier that *protects* the town from outside forces.

Answer (score 5):

The Zigzag-shaped paper streamers are called [Shide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shide_(Shinto)) and are used in Shinto rituals. They can be seen in many animes that are located near Shinto shrines. To create one you can cut out a piece of paper like the diagram below and fold the paper along the dotted lines.

[image: Shide cutout diagram]